# Vanilla Javascript - Animation with different timing

Tags: javascript

I would like to make an animation using **onscroll** in Vanilla Javascript. I have **2 classes**. The first one is **.photography_box** which is active and the second one is **.photography_box_active** which is not active. When i scroll down to 1500px my second class **.photography_box_active** kicks in and my animation is working great. My **.photography_box** consist of 12 boxes. When the animation happens all of them come in at the same time which is not what i want. I would like each one of them to come in one after the other. In jQuery i could use **$.each** but i would like to have the same effect using Vanilla Javascript. Can someone help me solve the problem?

Thanks

CSS code for my classes :

```
.photography_box {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50px);
    transform:translateX(-50px);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.photography_box_active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

JS code is :

```
var photoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("photography_box");

window.onscroll = function() {
    loopBox()
};

function loopBox(){
if ( window.pageYOffset > 1500 ){
     for ( f = 0; f <= photoBox.length -1; f++ ) {
     photoBox[f].classList.add("photography_box_active");
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Can you use a `setTimeout()` to delay the add of the `photography_box_active` class?

Comment: I have tried it but it just delay, and everything comes in all together. I would like to each one to come with different timing.

Comment: `setTimeout()` should work...Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Where would you add it?

Comment: Check out @VonD's answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` in your loop to delay the animation for each item based on its index. So if you want a delay of 150ms:

```
for ( f = 0; f < photoBox.length; f++ ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        photoBox[f].classList.add("photography_box_active");
    }, 150 * f);
}
```

Note that as you know in advance the number of items, and as you are using css transitions, this could be done purely in css, keeping your existing js code. Supposing your `.photography_box` items are in a `.box` container

```
.box .photography_box:nth-child(1)  { transition-delay: 0    }
.box .photography_box:nth-child(2)  { transition-delay: 0.05s }
// and so on...
```

quite cumbersome to write, especially with vendor-prefixes, but nothing annoying if you are using a css preprocessor like sass

Comment: Thanks for the reply VonD i have tried what u wrote but it doesnt seem to be working for some reason. What would you put in the - delay * f - . I have tried using 150 * (f+1) but its now working can u set a full example with the delay * f please

Comment: @NoName84 I meant `delay` to be a variable holding the value in milliseconds of the delay you want to apply to each item. I've updated my answer. Is it more clear this way ?

Comment: Yes now its working thanks for ur help and the tip for css.

Answer (score 0):

Example: array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach